# Display connected via DisplayPort disconnects, reconnects when resuming, resizing windows on display

Tags: display, sleep-wake, hdmi, displayport

I have a new [LG 29UM55 29" Ultrawide monitor](http://smile.amazon.com/LG-29UM55-Cineview-Monitor-2560x1080/dp/B00SKX47HG/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1436020575&sr=1-1&keywords=LG+29UM55), resolution of 2560 x 1080, connected via DisplayPort to my 2012 MacBook Air 13" via a [Cable Matters Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable](http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00C7RJQPY) that reportedly does have pin 20 wired correctly. I had previously tried connecting via HDMI, but as the manual for the display indicates, Macs are apparently unable to use the full native resolution when connected via HDMI.

A negative experience I'm having is that, **when the MBA goes to sleep, the display appears to disconnect**. This is noticeable only when waking it: the extra screen blanking of the display automatically reconnecting is almost imperceptible, and would otherwise be of negligible consequence, except for the result that **all of my windows that were on that display are resized to fit on the MBA's built-in screen's resolution**.

So, I find myself having to constantly re-maximize or rearrange windows whenever I walk away long enough for the screensaver to turn on and/or the computer goes to sleep. This is really aggravating, as I do arrange my windows quite particularly.

My options are seemingly thus:

- **Replace cable** - maybe this is a manifestation of the pin 20 problem, but the display *does* awaken, just dis/re-connects annoyingly.
- **Replace monitor** - maybe something is wrong with this unit or this model?

  - I don't have another DisplayPort monitor easily accessible, but I might be able to borrow one or at least find one I can use in a store just to demonstrate that it's a DisplayPort or OS X problem and not a unit/model problem.
- **Tweak something in OS X** - maybe there's a setting that I can alter that will disable this behavior, without having to disable screensaver or sleep. Suggestions welcome!
- **Replace MBA** - I'm already planning to pick up a new Macbook Pro this month, but I don't know if I'll get it in time to be within the display's return period, should I decide to return the display. I have a feeling this is not a reliable solution, because it's unlikely that the new machine wouldn't exhibit this behavior unless the behavior would change between Thunderbolt and Thunderbolt 2.
- **???** - this is where you ingenious answerers come in.

Comment: Related, less specific: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179928/can-i-prevent-os-x-from-resizing-and-moving-windows-when-sleeping-while-attached?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with OSX & Windows. HDMI devices are able to be queried by the connected computer to check display resolutions even when powered off, so this is a non-issue. DisplayPort devices seem to not have this feature. When Windows & OSX wakes up from a sleep state, it checks to see if the monitor is still connected but finds the DP monitor to be in powersaving mode and cannot determine if your 2560 x 1080 desktop is still there and so resizes everything down.

Windows users appear to have a bassackwards solution:

1. Connect monitor via DisplayPort and HDMI/DVI
2. Configure Windows to mirror desktop on the *2* displays.

Comment: Got a solution that would work for OSX?

Comment: Wake the monitor manually before you wake the Mac.